# Вопрос по htaccess и url

Tags: .htaccess

Имеется правило в htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)([.])(php|html)?$ /index.php?app=constructor&modules=$1&type=$2 [QSA]
```

От данной строки я хочу получить следующие, что при заходе по ссылке, к примеру `site.ru/page.php`, к index файлу шёл запрос `modules = page`, `type = php`, но при моём случае, мне выдаёт 500 ошибку, подскажите, в чём проблема, а точнее, как правильнее составить правило url в данном случае?

Comment: как минимум, вот так `^([a-z]+)\.(php|html)?$

Comment: и добавить `RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$` перед

Comment: Не рабочий вариант.